# JSOM running only in Edit mode of Script Editor

Tags: jsom, script-webpart, script-editor-webpart

I am using script editor for JSOM which includes java-script and css tags.

My jsom code is working fine only when URL is  `http://portalurl?PageView=Shared&InitialTabId=Ribbon.WebPartPage&VisibilityContext=WSSWebPartPage`

Can any one please help me in knowing what's the issue and how can I solve it?

Comment: what are the webpart properties ?

Comment: Try adding the type="text/javascript" in the <script> tag references, like this

Answer (score 0):

edit the page where the web part is placed and select the webpart by checking it, and look for the webpart whether it is minimize/restore.
If it is showing option as restore then click on restore and your script may work.

Answer (score 0):

It may be the time it takes to load the libraries (like sp.js and your oyher dependencies). When you are in the edit URL it takes more time to load Standard sharepoint components and the your script works. Try to use javascript settimeout (https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_settimeout.asp)  and asks to wait for one second (just as test) if it works use SP.SOD (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff408081(v=office.14).aspx)